# how to start a new activity after login success?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

i want to start a new activity after login success. that is when login goes correct a new activity should start automatically...i dont know where to mention startactivity. please help me with this, im a newbie to android.
this is my code...

```
    public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    Context ctx;
    BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx =ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Information....");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String reg_url = "";
        String login_url = "";
        String method = params[0];
        if (method.equals("register")) {
            String name = params[1];
            String user_name = params[2];
            String user_pass = params[3];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(reg_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                //httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_pass", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_pass, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();
                InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();
                //httpURLConnection.connect();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return "Registration Success...";
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        else if(method.equals("login"))
        {
            String login_name = params[1];
            String login_pass = params[2];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("login_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("login_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_pass,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String response = "";
                String line  = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    response+= line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return response;


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result.equals("Registration Success..."))
        {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Pardon the unsolicited advice: if there are more than two possible results from doInBackground, I'd suggest changing onPostExecute to take an Integer argument so you can do a switch-case on the result value: eg "Unknown username, connection timeout," etc.

Comment: Also, not a good idea to put live URLs or other potentially sensitive or proprietary information in the code you post. Might want to clean up those URLS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put intent in your onPostExecute method like this :

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result == null)
        {
            // do what you want to do
        }
        else if(result.equals("Registration Success..."))
        {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(result.contains("Login Success")) // msg you get from success like "Login Success"
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(ctx,NewActivity.class);
            ctx.startActivity(i);
            alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();
        }

    }
```

**Edit :**
If you want to call new activity after login success then put intent in else part.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but if i put intent  here then it will execute after registration success...right?
but i want it after login success

Comment: @rijoraju it helps you?

Comment: buddy im getting some error...cannot resolve startactivity method

Comment: @rijoraju  use context.startActivity(i);

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(BackgroundTask.this,Main2Activity.class);
            BackgroundTask.startActivity(i);

this is what i did..but it still gives me error..
sorry im just a noob

Comment: @rijoraju use ctx.startActivity(i);

Comment: Unless your asynctask has a reference to a Context, you'll get the unresolved error for startActivity.

Comment: @rijoraju check edited answer based on your variable used.

Comment: @rijoraju it helps you?

Comment: thanks sanat shukla...it worked, really thanks.
and one more thing...can i delete this
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Information....");
}

Comment: @rijoraju if you don't want alert dialog then delete it.

Comment: Upvoted. I have no idea why someone would downvote an answer that 1) solves the problem and 2) shows that the person read all the code provided. Unless of course the downvoter didn't bother to read everything.

Comment: @sanatshukla just one question what if registration fails and also login fails?

Comment: even after login fails...it still going to the next activity..this is not what i wanted..i wanted the app to move to next activity only when login success

Comment: @sanatshukla not working
now even without fillling the login details if i click on login the new activity starts

Comment: @rijoraju sorry for late reply its my fault. I edited my answer. First need to check for null and then other conditions.

Comment: still the same result..without any login details it moves to new activity on click

Comment: @rijoraju what u get in login success ?

Comment: without applying your code..i get a alert saying login success...welcome rijo,
but after applying your code even without entering any detail login it moves to new activity

Comment: @rijoraju check my edited answer. Put your exact msg value to else if condition.

Comment: the exact msg i get is ....Login Success...Welcome Rijo Raju
where Rijo Raju is retrieved from the database but i dont know about welcome.

Comment: Use status code from server side for easiness. Otherwise it becomes complicated.

Comment: still im not able to do it...i feel like this app not gonna work

Comment: @rijoraju Implementation is not good for the web service. Web service always return something like status code (200,400 etc) based on which you can identify what you want to do next in your app. For last time i m doing something in answer check edited answer after some time

Comment: @rijoraju answer edited , now give it a last chance.

Comment: buddy can you help with something more.

Comment: buddy i want to show all the data from the mysql database on my app...i tried different method..not working for me...please help me with this
i tried this method
http://www.geeks.gallery/retrieve-data-from-mysql-database-using-php-and-displaying-it-by-tableview-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

In postExecute() method you have to check the method variable, please check below code.

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
AlertDialog alertDialog;
Context ctx;
String method;
BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
{
    this.ctx =ctx;
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Information....");
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String reg_url = "http://thecapitalcitychurch.16mb.com/new/register.php";
    String login_url = "http://thecapitalcitychurch.16mb.com/new/login.php";
    method = params[0];
    if (method.equals("register")) {
        String name = params[1];
        String user_name = params[2];
        String user_pass = params[3];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            //httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("user_pass", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_pass, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            OS.close();
            InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            IS.close();
            //httpURLConnection.connect();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return "Registration Success...";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    else if(method.equals("login"))
    {
        String login_name = params[1];
        String login_pass = params[2];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("login_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("login_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_pass,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String response = "";
            String line  = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                response+= line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return response;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(result.equals("Registration Success..."))
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    if(method.equals("login") && result.equals("Login Success..."))
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(ctx, Dashboard.class);
        ctx.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You have to declare method variable global in the BackgroundTask class.

Comment: sorry buddy im still getting error
could you just declare it please its a request

Comment: did you added this sentence- method = params[0];

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: i tried with your code...but it not starting a new activity on login success..its only giving the alert that is login success

Answer (score 0):

call in your onPostexecute

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        try {Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
}catch(Exception e){}}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to start another activity once your login call gets succeed then you can start another activity either from the call back of login response or from the onpostExecute method of AsyncTask.

For implementing callback in API flow, you just need to create an interface  which has few methods without body(only declaration) and these methods must have implemented in the class which implements that interface. Pass this interface object as a constructor of asyncTask. Once login call gets succeed you need to call the method of that interface and inside that method you can start another activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Login extends Activity  {

    Button b1,b2;
    EditText ed1,ed2;

    TextView tx1;
    int counter = 3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);

        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        ed2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        tx1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tx1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(ed1.getText().toString().equals("admin") &&
                        ed2.getText().toString().equals("admin")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Redirecting...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // open new activity after successful login
                    Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivities.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();


                } else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Wrong Credencials",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            tx1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tx1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    counter--;
                    tx1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));

                    if (counter == 0) {
                        b1.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }


            }
        });

        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).